# No puedo redireccionar a una página desde un SweetAlert

Tags: php, mysql, sweetalert

tengo mi pagina datos.php la misma que viene con datos post desde un formulario que esta en una pagina formulario.php y luego de insertar datos y de  presionar ok no redirecciona a esta pagina /siscoer/vistas/emergencia.php  porque sera.....
$CreateSql = "INSERT INTO scemergencia (numero,iddestipofampeligro)VALUES ('$numero','$scfamtipopeligro');

```
if (mysqli_query($connection, $CreateSql) )
    {

    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      jQuery(function(){
          swal({type: "success",
              title: "¡Bien!",
              text: "Registro Insertado",
          }).then(function() {
              window.location.href = "/siscoer/vistas/emergencia.php";
          });
      });
      </script>';


    } else {
     echo "<p>No se agregó...</p>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importa esto debajo de la importación de Jquery:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Y el nuevo código para llamar a tu sweet alert sería así:

```
jQuery(function(){
          swal({
              icon: "success",
              title: "¡Bien!",
              text: "Registro Insertado",
          }).then((value) => {
            if(value){
              window.location.href = "tu/ruta";
            }
          });
      });
```

Fuente: https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#installation

Comment: Gracias lo probare

Comment: NO funciona sigo en la misma pagina y no redirecciona porque......

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta, vuelve a leerla

Comment: gracia amigo pero igual no redirecciona porque sera.....

Comment: Yo probé el código de mi respuesta y funciona bien, abre la consola del navegador y ve que error te da, con el código de tu pregunta decía que la función "then" no existía, revisa y me dices

Comment: Prueba quitando así  "siscoer/vistas/emergencia.php", a mi me funcionó

Answer (score 0):

Prueba quitando el *href*:

```
jQuery(function(){
      swal({type: "success",
          title: "¡Bien!",
          text: "Registro Insertado",
      }).then(function() {
          window.location = "/siscoer/vistas/emergencia.php";
      });
  });
```